# What is the use of / in the following css statement

Tags: html, css, background, slash, css-backgrounds

I want to know the use of '/' in the following css statement:-

```
background: url(a.jpg) center bottom / cover no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to separate background-position and background-size value. Check the [formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#formal_syntax) of the `background` property:

> ```
> background = 
>   [ <bg-layer># , ]? <final-bg-layer>  
>
> <bg-layer> = 
>   <bg-image>                      ||
>   <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]?  ||
>   <repeat-style>                  ||
>   <attachment>                    ||
>   <box>                           ||
>   <box>
> ```

This allows you to use length-percentage values for both entities, e.g.:

```
background: 4% / 2%;
```

is equivalent to:

```
background-position: 4%;
background-size: 2%;
```

The CSS shorthand rule from the question:

```
background: url(a.jpg) center bottom / cover no-repeat;
```

is equivalent to

```
background-image: url(a.jpg);
background-position: center bottom;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```